# Is it possible to modify a specification of the real Hokuyo Lidar, not the vitual?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm ROS-kinetic user of Ubuntu 16.04.

As far as my knowledge, my Hokuyo lidar [UBG-04LX-F01](https://www.hokuyo-aut.jp/search/single.php?serial=164) has 240 degrees of the detection range.

But I just checked the real range through

> > $ rostopic echo /scan

and it returns `1.57079637051` as the `angle_max`, which means 90 degrees.

I've also finished testing whether the UBG-04LX-F01 detects 240 degrees ranges, and it couldn't detect the outside 180 degrees ranges.

However, the reference link says UBG-04LX-F01 has 240 ranges, not 180.

So I wonder whether it is possible to modify a REAL sensor's specification concerning detection, not a virtual one of the Gazebo simulator.

And this is the returned message of `/scan` topic.

```
header: 
       seq: 311
       stamp: 
         secs: 1624521860
         nsecs:  35275086
       frame_id: "laser"
 angle_min: -1.57079637051
 angle_max: 1.57079637051
 angle_increment: 0.00613592332229
 time_increment: 2.71259814326e-05
 scan_time: 0.0277769993991
 range_min: 0.019999999553
 range_max: 5.59999990463
 ranges: [1.527999997138977, 1.531999945640564,...]
```

And I'm not familiar with a sensor driver, so I'm not sure which one is I'm using but I usually do

> > $ roslaunch urg_node urg_lidar.launch

One more thing, I always have to do this,

> > $ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0

If anyone who has ever used a UBG-04LX-F01 sensor or other Hokuyo lidar sensors, would you please give me advice?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/380977/is-it-possible-to-modify-a-specification-of-the-real-hokuyo-lidar,-not-the-vitual?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2021-06-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2021-06-24**:
Well, obviously the sensor spec says its 240°, however, you're not saying anythinig about the driver you use. This might be a limittion in the driver. Or, it is not symmetric around 0. Please specify which driver you use, how you start it (show launch and config files) and ideally also the output of one scan topic (you can truncate ranges and intensities, but the rest would be very helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm assuming you are only launching the provided launch file from the `urg_node` package.
Basically, what you are doing with that is to configure it to only send data within that angle range. You need to properly set the [respective parameters](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/kinetic-devel/launch/urg_lidar.launch#L17-L18)

Check the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/urg_node#Using_udev_to_Give_Hokuyos_Consistent_Device_Names) for a solution for the `chmod` issue.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2021-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2021-06-24**:
Thank you, I've just forgotten that there are some parameters I can modify for a while. Now the lidar can detect the range of 240 degrees. Thanks again!